# CriteriaQuery entity.list has value

Tags: hibernate, criteriaquery

I have an entity that has a list of enitities connected to it. `Customer.roles = List<Role>()`

Now I get `roleId` as input and I'd like to know if customer has the role connected to it.

I've tried several Ways using `CriteriaQuery` but haven't yet found the right way. How to do this using `CriteriaQuery`.

Idealy I'd like something like:
`fromCustomer.get("roles").has(roleId)`

Comment: can you give me a table description of both tables *Customer* and *Role*

Comment: `Customer` table has just the usual fields: id, firstname, lastname etc. Role table has `id, customer_id, role_type_id, valid_from, valid_to`